# SQL query ORDER BY gives different result every once in a while (5 second interval)

Tags: mysql, query, order-by

```
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_product dg ON dg.post_id = wp_posts.ID 
AND ( dg.location IN ('XV', 'QV', 'DH') ) 
AND (0 OR (dg.srp = 1) OR (dg.SoldDate > (now() - interval 30 DAY) 
AND dg.isPremium = 0 AND dg.SoldDate != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
AND dg.SoldDate IS NOT NULL AND price > 0 AND NoImage = 0)) 
AND ( dg.deleted IS NULL OR dg.deleted <> 1 ) 
WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_product_info_new' ) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY dg.SoldDate IS NULL, dg.SoldDate ASC, dg.isPremium DESC LIMIT 0, 30
```

This query gives me a different result every time on my local development environment even though the database doesn't change at all. The same number of product. I checked the count of the main table it queries and the number doesn't change. So I am wondering if there's a way to stop it from randomizing the results every once and then. Also, I don't see anything that can make the result randomized.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/71784268/20860. Please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: Your query is not correct. Enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY and ensure. *`ORDER BY dg.SoldDate IS NULL, dg.SoldDate ASC, dg.isPremium DESC`* Without these columns or expressions included into GROUP BY expression the value used in the sorting is indefinite, it is indefinitely selected from all existing values in a group. Also the rows for which the ORDER BY expression is the same are ordered indefinitely in a group.

Answer (score 1):

Add `, wp_posts.ID` to the end of the `ORDER BY` to make it deterministic.

And follow Akina's advice.